# Maven: remove jar files when jar with dependencies had been created

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-assembly-plugin

I have 4 modules
my general pom is like this:

```
<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<name>Modules</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
    <module>B</module>
    <module>C</module>
    <module>D</module>
    <module>E</module>
</modules>
```

In module E I have the main class so in the pom of E i have:

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
</parent>
<artifactId>E</artifactId>
<name>E</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>D</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>group</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

...

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Mainclass</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

when I run mvn package; it creates B.jar, C.jar, D.jar and E-jar-with-dependencies.jar.
I want only create the last jar because B,C and D are in the E-jar-with-dependencies.jar

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps but,

It is normal that B, C and D are created since they are needed by E.
If you run `mvn package` in the root folder maven will build all modules, which is expected.

But if you only need E you can run `mvn package` in E's directory. This however will use last build B,C and D dependencies (installed in repository), without rebuiling them.

Comment: I need to build them but i only want to add them on E. I dont need b.jar, c.jar and d.jar anymore.